# drop rows in pandas dataframe that are not meeting the conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and need to clean `Status` column. My data looks like this:

```
id        Status
123       100%
124       0%
125       1%
126       100%
127       0.25%
```

I want to exclude all the rows that are NOT 100% or 0%. The type of the column is `object`

I want my data looks like this:

```
id        Status
123       100%
124       0%
126       100%
```

I have tried the following:

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.Status == '100%') & (df.Status == '0%')].index)
```

But that actually doesn't change the dataset at all.

Thank you!

Comment: `df = df[~df.Status.isin(['100%','0%])]`?

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Please add a `'` after `0%`.

Comment: oh Duh!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally select the rows that meet your criteria and set that as the new dataframe value

```
df = df.loc[(df['Status']  == '100%') | (df['Status']  == '0%')]
```

Edit: "|" instead of "&" since both cannot be true at the same time, thus returning 0 results.

Comment: This somehow gave me 0 results back.

Comment: Because the values can't be both 100% and 0% so this line of code works if we use `or` instead. Just like mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

First, you say "or", so you need the pipe operator, not ampersand (even with correct coding, "Status" will never be both 0% and 100%). Second, you correctly call the index from your conditions, but you need to pass the index to `drop` as an index. This should work:

```
df.drop(index=df[(df.Status=="100%" )| (df.Status=="0%")].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['100%'], ['0%'], ['1%'],['100%'],['0.25%']], columns=['Status'], index=[123, 124,125,126,127])
df = df[(df.Status == '100%') | (df.Status == '0%')]
```